# Obj-c NSTimer - Slower than expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, delay, nstimer

I have to do **heavy** operation every < 1s. I'm using NSTimer, but its not that accurate as i expected... I'm using 2 timers. One to update data in my model and 2nd to update my views (few labels and custom 'fancy-circle' progress bar)

Ok... my code:

```
_valueTimer = 
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
                                   target:self
                                 selector:@selector(counterTask)
                                 userInfo:nil
                                  repeats:YES];

_progressTimer =
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                   target:self
                                 selector:@selector(updateViews) // heavy stuff here
                                 userInfo:nil
                                  repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:_progressTimer
                           forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

As you can see `_progressTimer` selector is run every 0.1 sec. 
One of the views is my HH:MM:SS time (data from first timer!). It display different time than real time when my progressbar is updating (**heavy operation**) -> 10 sec in app == 12 sec in real time... Its too much difference. When I comment my progress bar update - it all works correctly

Could you tell me how to force my timer to run exactly after my interval? Or skip one cycle when its too much for it to handle? The most important thing is to not slow down...

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `NSTimer` to keep time; just use it do things periodically.  Instead of getting the elapsed time from the `NSTimer`, use another clock method and subtract the current time from the start time.  Also doing something 100 times a second is far too frequent for an average app (OSX or iOS); there is no need for it.

Comment: If you need to get an accurate time interval, you could use `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent` but calling something that frequently may not be necessary. If you wanted to do something successively, why not use a `while` loop?

Comment: Because `NSTimer` is scheduled in the main runloop, when you are doing heavy work you will essentially slow down the runloop, thus slowing down the timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found solution. Maybe not perfect, but it works.
In `counterTask` method instead of increasing my `_actualTime` value by 0.01... I calculate real interval between 'ticks' like this:

```
  NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
  NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
  startDate = currentDate;
  _actualTime += timeInterval;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `CADisplayLink` timer to synchronize animation/drawing with the refresh rate of the device's display (ie, 60 times per second for iOS devices).

```
self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleDisplayLinkTimerFired:)];
//_displayLink.frameInterval = 3; // slows the updates for debugging
[_displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Because your method (here, `handleDisplayLinkTimerFired`:)  will be called frequently, you don't want to do heavy processing or you risk dropping frames.